# ActionScript 3/Flash CC - Loop background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I just started learning AS3, I've been using Adobe Flash for a while.

I'm making a simple "Avoiding Game", 
but the problem is that I want the background with stars (white dots) to move, but eventually it will run in to it's end (white space).

I made a temporary solution by copy/paste:ing the bg over and over again, but it only lasts a few minutes.

Is there a way to loop the background?

or even better:

Is there a way to random generate moving stars?

I guess it's quite simple, but I'm a newbie.

[image: Manually looped background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I made a temporary solution by copy/paste:ing the bg over and over again*

---

If you are familiar with the `Timeline`, I will give you simple solution.

Yes, you need to copy/past your `background`, but only once.
 
Stack original and copied `background`, so copied version begins at the end of original `background`. Create animation by offsetting original `background` on it's width, so copy version of the background will be in the same place - at start.

Now you will have infinite loop for the background, because first and last frames are equal ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I already created an alternative (and better) solution. I made the background black, and on a different layer I made some stars and made AS3 random generate their `X` and `Y` cordinates. This anserws the question, though :)